# Is there any C++ coding standard like PSR-1/2

Tags: c++, coding-style, standards

I was searching for C++ coding standard.

I found lots of standards:

- Google C++ Style Guide
- High Integrity C++ Coding Standard Version 4.0
- ...

Is there any C++ coding standard like PSR-1/2<sup>1</sup> that every C++ developer follows?

---

<sub>1) PHP Standard Recommendation. PSR-1: Basic Coding Standard. PSR-2: Coding Style Guide.</sub>

Comment: What's `PSR-1/2` standard actually?

Comment: PSR: PHP Standard Recommendation. 
PSR-1: Basic Coding Standard.
PSR-2: Coding Style Guide.

Comment: Is it wrong now to advertise for [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines)? Its intention is clearly what you look for I think. Edit: [here in style](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines)

Comment: @Maikel: Wow, it says a lot about C++ that a "guide to using [it] well" is tl;dr

Comment: @Maikel Thanks. Could you post it as answer.

Comment: @mmhyamin: But it's _not_ an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I think the given answers are already good i would like to add the following comment:

There is a rather new project [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines) which tries to do what you are looking for (at least I think so). It is still in an ongoing process but IMHO it is already worth to take a look. There are also some nice talks about these guidelines

[CppCon 2015: Bjarne Stroustrup “Writing Good C++14”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OEu9C51K2A)

and

[CppCon 2015: Herb Sutter "Writing Good C++14... By Default"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEx5DNLWGgA)

which explains its main purpose quite nicely. They emphasize static code analysis alot and in my opinion they try to push it alot with these guidelines.

But an important information is

> FAQ.6: Have these guidelines been approved by the ISO C++ standards
>   committee? Do they represent the consensus of the committee?
>
> No. These guidelines are outside the standard. They are intended to
>   serve the standard, and be maintained as current guidelines about how
>   to use the current Standard C++ effectively. We aim to keep them in
>   sync with the standard as that is evolved by the committee.

In the end it means, it is just another set of rules in the sense of the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any C++ coding standard like PSR-1/2 that every C++ developer follows?

The C++ language standard is made official by the [ISO C++ Committee](https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee).

The standard comes with iterations and versionings (like c++-11, c++-14, c++-17) that are (mostly) backwards compatible.

That's actually what *every C++ developer needs to follow*.

---

If you're actually asking about coding style guides, that's a different thing, and no there aren't any *common* standards, beyond what's forbidden/discouraged from the c++ standard language.

---

Well, rethinking the *standard style guide* wording, there actually are established coding style standards like e.g. [Misra C++](http://www.misra-cpp.com/).

You'll need to consider fulfilling these to get into certain business domains. You may think these are silly, and too restrictive, but still the customer wants you to fulfill these style guides.

It's your choice, and you'll need to estimate your extra efforts and costs (for e.g. investing in a static analysis tool that confirms standard compliance), and put that on the customers bill.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I actually mean the coding style standard. I know the PHP developers from my city and university. Everyone of them follow the PSR standard. So, their code looks like same. This standard is like a Bible to them. I am looking for that kind of standard. As I said earlier I am new in C++ programming, when I am looking at others code first I have to scan top to bottom where they defined or declared what. Everyone's coding style is different. Everyone is using their own style. This is frustrating for a beginner like me.

Comment: @mmhyamin That's probably because PHP is an untyped and very clumsy language compared to c++, where many things are already covered by the mentioned c++ language standard.

Comment: @mmhyamin: _"I know the PHP developers from my city and university. Everyone of them follow the PSR standard."_ I find that extremely hard to believe. Have you really polled absolutely everyone?

Comment: @mmhyamin: _"I am new in C++ programming, when I am looking at others code first I have to scan top to bottom where they defined or declared what. Everyone's coding style is different. Everyone is using their own style."_ Then that answers your question, doesn't it? Clearly, there is _not_ one true C++ coding style. Or you wouldn't have this experience.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet By everyone I mean the professionals.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

If there were a single style guide that everybody followed, why would there be multiple style guides?

For what it's worth, I don't follow anyone else's style guide, and in my opinion neither should you.

Your job may require you to follow a certain guide, but then you wouldn't be asking us which to use.

Notice that I refuse to call these style guides "standards".

Comment: _"For what it's worth, I don't follow anyone else's style guide"_ Well,as mentioned, that might restrict you to get into some certain business domains with your code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: How so? If I ever change jobs and my new job requires me to follow a style guide, I'll simply do that. In the meantime, I'll continue doing whatever I like. I don't see the big deal about style guides.

Comment: Maybe *every developer* could follow that style guide sometimes, like every third Wednesday. Just to see how its doing.

Comment: Some customers want you to fulfill Misra C++ coding style guides to a certain level (popular in the automobile industry), so you have to fulfill it or you're out of the project, that simple :-P

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet _"I don't work for those customers."_ Well, that's a good choice :-D ...

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet For collaboration I think we need a standard. I am attending competitive programming workshop at my university. We have to form a group (max 3 members) in next month. So, if we don't follow any standard then how will we collaborate with each other? It will waste a lot of time to understand other member's code.

Comment: @mmhyamin: If you can only understand C++ code that conforms to _your_ chosen style guide, something's wrong. It may be more convenient to read code in the same style, but any C++ programmer should be able to read code written in the language no matter what style guide is used. That being said, collaborating with others to create a single piece of code _is_ a good opportunity for choosing a style guide that everyone can agree on, to save time and avoid frustrations. But that's not what your question asked.